# MySQL query not displaying all applicable rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently stuck on a problem where I need to return rate_type, loan_id, balance, and percentage of balance among loans of the same rate_type.

[image: Given table - submissions]

[image: submissions data types]

```
select rate_type, loan_id, balance, balance/sum(balance) from submissions
where rate_type = "variable"
```

[image: Which returns this.]

When I run this code, only 1 row returns, any idea how to output all rows where rate_type = "variable" ?

Comment: what is percent of balance?

Comment: Please don't post code, data or error messages as screen shots. It's difficult to set up your problem for test, and they're not searchable. See [ask]

Comment: @sid 11% for my output, I did the math and for loan_id 2, it is 11% of all variable loans.

Comment: @gandolfini Which version of MySql you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**: You're not dividing the balance with sum of total balance, instead you're just adding them up.

**Solution**:

You first need to query normally like you do

```
SELECT balance, interest_rate, rate_type, loan_id FROM submissions
```

then use `inner join` to sum all the balance

```
inner JOIN (SELECT sum(balance)  AS total FROM submissions where  rate_type = "variable") balance on submissions.rate_type = 'variable'
```

now that you have the total balance too, you need to SELECT this from the main query and do the math, so your 1st statement would be

```
SELECT balance, interest_rate, rate_type, loan_id, round(balance * 100 / balance.total, 2) as percentage_balance FROM submissions
```

[Demo](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/ESYDCB3uxUl)